# c# Check if a file path contains a specific directory

Tags: c#, .net, filepath

When I get a path like c:\folder1\a12\somefile.txt, I want to check if the file name contains a directory c:\folder1\a1.

The above file name should return false.

The code does not have access to the file system in question. It does not need to check the existence of the file or the folder. Just need to follow the file and directory name convention.

It would be nice if the code could handle alternate path separator/UNIX paths.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: My code was written during .NET 1.1 and with too many if conditions. I was looking for something new in .NET 4+ and couldn't find any quick solution. I was hoping someone has already solved this problem at least for Windows paths.

Comment: Can you use `string.Contains` or `string.StartsWith`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply check whether your file path starts with the directory path. Don't forget to suffix the directory path with the separator to avoid false positives

```
public static bool IsFileBelowDirectory(string fileInfo, string directoryInfo, string separator)
{
    var directoryPath = string.Format("{0}{1}"
    , directoryInfo
    , directoryInfo.EndsWith(separator) ? "": separator);

    return fileInfo.StartsWith(directoryPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to normalize separators for both sides.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is right, and what's more you may want to take a hard look at the OrdinalIgnoreCase parameter since Unix path are usually case sensitive. Your call, either parametrize the value or wrap it in a class that would be built depending on your environment

Comment: Doesn't take the parent directory notation (..) into account. Also you should use Path.TrimEndingDirectorySeparator instead of having a parameter only for the separator.
Here is another solution (with ignoreCase, a boolean argument):
``Path.GetFullPath(fileInfo).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(directoryInfo), ignoreCase ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase : StringComparison.Ordinal);``

Comment: No one understand seperator mean? please give an example.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
public bool isSubDir(string parentPath, string childPath)
{
    var parentUri = new Uri(parentPath);
    var childUri = new DirectoryInfo(childPath).Parent;
    while(childUri != null)
    {
        if(new Uri(childUri.FullName) == parentUri)
        {
            return true ;
        }
        childUri = childUri.Parent;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think that the best way is to use string.Contains() to check if the full path contains the folder you want

```
public static bool IsUnderDirectory(string fullpath, string directoryName)
{
   return fullpath.Contains(string.Format(@"{0}\",directoryName));
}
```

i hope this help you

Comment: This will work for Windows folder. Just need to make sure there isn't already a trailing separator.

Comment: you need to compare nocase.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for windows & unix style paths I think, and doesn't rely on the files/directories actually existing.

```
string someFile = @"/var/folder1/a12/somefile.txt";
// true
Console.WriteLine("Contains?: {0}", someFile.ContainsSubPath(@"/var/folder1/a12/"));
// false
Console.WriteLine("Contains?: {0}", someFile.ContainsSubPath(@"/var/folder1/a1/"));

// windows style
someFile = @"c:\folder1\a12\somefile.txt";
// true
Console.WriteLine("Contains?: {0}", someFile.ContainsSubPath(@"c:\folder1\a12\"));
// false
Console.WriteLine("Contains?: {0}", someFile.ContainsSubPath(@"c:\folder1\a1\"));
```

Here is the code for the extension method..

```
public static bool ContainsSubPath(this string pathToFile, string subPath)
{
    pathToFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile) + "\\";
    string searchPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(subPath) + "\\";

    bool containsIt = pathToFile.IndexOf(searchPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;

    return containsIt;
}
```